# How to get casperjs POST result if the response body is simply an URL (not HTML or XML etc)

Tags: http, phantomjs, casperjs

I sniffed the HTTP packages and I know the response is something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 18:32:14 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 175
Connection: keep-alive

http://www.example.com/abc.mp3
```

Note that the `Content-Type` has been wrongly returned as `text/xml`. The actual response body is just an URL. I've tried `casper.getPageContent()` and `require('utils').dump(this.page.content);` and some other methods trying to get the correct response body (the URL) but all failed.

The result of `casper.getPageContent()` is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body><parsererror style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black"><h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3><div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 1 at column 1: Start tag expected.</div><h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3></parsererror></body></html>
```

My question is, how can I get the URL in the body of the HTTP response? Thanks.

BTW, you can use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)'s AutoResponder to fake this response to do the test if needed.

Comment: Write an angry email to them asking why they would set the content type to xml if it is not xml. You can experiment with the `setHeader()` function from the [`page.onResourceRequested`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html) event (`"resource.requested"` in CasperJS). To try to request proper Content-Types.

Comment: Thanks Artjom, I know that's may be the final resort. But it's not an option for now because it requires a lot of communication. Do you think it's possible to solve the problem just by using some casperjs or phantomjs tricks?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the direction! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Sadly I still can't make it work.

Comment: @ArtjomB., I finally found a way to solve my problem. I found the HTTP post is successful; It's just the CasperJS or PhantomJS can't correctly parse its response body. I used [FiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore) to write a .NET application to capture this response and write the response body to a file. Then I use CaserJS to read the file and I get what I want. It's tedious but it solved the problem.

Comment: @user130268 sounds like an amazing idea!  I have the same problem.  Does the .NET code (with Fiddler) also call the casper/phantom scripts or have you built a custom proxy server?